# Fullpage js - Can I add another fullpage section that is visible only on mobile screen?

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, anchor, fullpage.js, sections

I have 3 sections in total in web view. But when it comes to mobile view, I need one more section in between the second and the last section.

Anchors are provided for each section of the web view. Now, how do I add one more anchor for the section that is added only on mobile?

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

Anchors can not be added dynamically.
You would have to destroy and initialize fullPage.js again by using `fullpage_api.destroy()` and then initializing fullPage.js with the new anchors.